# Facebook Sdk Compatibility

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on Integrating the new Facebook SDK into my android application, but Facebook sdk 4.7 supports only android 4.xx and above, is there another way I could use to make it work on all devices? I thought of using facebook SDK 3 but it only supports up to android API 15 if am not mistaken, or it means I should rewrite my code for SDK 3.0 and SDK 4.7? all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use facebook sdk 4.5, from 4.6 onward minimum API is 15

Comment: thank you, if i could mark this answer 10 i was gonna do so